# Disable falling back to the system locale for Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I've a Spring Boot 2.0.1 project using Spring Data REST, Hibernate, HATEOAS, etc.
I need to disable the falling back to system locale for `rest-messages` properties.

Following useful hint from @wilkinsona [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2392#issuecomment-379198120) I tried to customize che behaviour but seems more complex than expected:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(RepositoryRestProperties.class)
public class CustomRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
    public static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryRestProperties properties;
    @Autowired
    private RepositoryRestConfiguration repositoryRestConfiguration;

    public CustomRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration(ApplicationContext context, ObjectFactory<ConversionService> conversionService) {
        super(context, conversionService);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        this.properties.applyTo(repositoryRestConfiguration);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public MessageSourceAccessor resourceDescriptionMessageSourceAccessor() {
        try {
            PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
            propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("rest-messages.properties"));
            propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

            ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
            messageSource.setBasename("classpath:rest-messages");
            messageSource.setCommonMessages(propertiesFactoryBean.getObject());
            messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

            messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);

            return new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource);

        } catch (Exception o_O) {
            throw new BeanCreationException("resourceDescriptionMessageSourceAccessor", "", o_O);
        }
    }
}
```

Following hints I came up with this configuration class but when I run the application I've this exception (truncated because it is recursive):

```
org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.test.server.RebusApplication.main(RebusApplication.java:15) [classes/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:409) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repositoryRestConfiguration'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryRestConfiguration' defined in class path resource [com.test/server/config/CustomRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'customRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'repositoryRestConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at
```

I have the feeling the problem is `repositoryRestConfiguration` but I don't know how to fix it.
Do you have some advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
CustomRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration
```

RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration has a method repositoryRestConfiguration()
which Spring uses to create the bean of type RepositoryRestConfiguration

But you are also trying to

```
 @Autowired
private RepositoryRestConfiguration repositoryRestConfiguration;
```

This causes a cyclic dependency, which leads to the exception.

If you are not using the field 'repositoryRestConfiguration', just remove it.

If you really need to access the RepositoryRestConfiguration inside your CustomRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration, call the method repositoryRestConfiguration() from the super class instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I already tried calling super.repositoryRestConfiguration() but I had an Exception as well: `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: And btw I need to get repositoryRestConfiguration because I need to call `this.properties.applyTo(repositoryRestConfiguration);` as pointed out here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2392#issuecomment-379198120